# How would I add a download link into the second image of this script

Tags: javascript, html

This is the script I am working with (below)

As the images are built into the script I am unsure on how to add a download link/link to website. to the second image

The script changes from image 1 to image 2 after 10 seconds and then I want then to be able to CLICK image 2 (like a button)

Here is the script I am working with if you could maybe help me with adding it in or tell me what I need to add in and where that would be much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head> 
<body> 
<img id="img1" src="https://i.makeagif.com/media/1-28-2016/N_tuzx.gif" /> 
<script> 
setTimeout(function(){ 
document.getElementById("img1").src = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fgPjlOk4PWc/WzQrQ_NBxRI/AAAAAAAAAWw/bvINTos17nssgQXqhevQq97dvUfzINdhgCPcBGAYYCw/s320/download-2062197_960_720.png";
}, 10000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

After you've changed `src` of the image, just add a `"click"` event listener to it

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById("img1").src = "link";
    document.getElementById("img1").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
         // when someone clicks
    });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Hello thank you for taking the time to helping me. How would I add that script you just sent into mine ? Or would I just place it below ? Sorry I am very new to this but Eager to learn

Comment: @PaulineMckenzie You could consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi how would I implement your script in to my script to get it to work ? Again thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and replace Download_Link with desired link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
       <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="wrapper">
          <img id="img1" src="https://i.makeagif.com/media/1-28-2016/N_tuzx.gif" /> 
       </div>
       <script> 
          setTimeout(function(){

          var mydiv = document.getElementById("img1");

          var aTag = document.createElement('a');
          aTag.setAttribute('href',"Download_Link");

          aTag.setAttribute('download', true);

          aTag.appendChild(mydiv);

          document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(aTag);

          document.getElementById("img1").src = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fgPjlOk4PWc/WzQrQ_NBxRI/AAAAAAAAAWw/bvINTos17nssgQXqhevQq97dvUfzINdhgCPcBGAYYCw/s320/download-2062197_960_720.png";
          }, 10000);
       </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```